# Open source Jquery widget that behaves like the google+ invite textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, open-source, textbox

I was wondering if the hive mind knew of an open source widget (probably a jquery type thing) that behaves like the google plus invite control[image].

That is, textbox autocomplete, but selected before current choice being typed become their own span in the textbox.

I could do this from scratch but figure I would save some time and see if there was already something like this out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Autosuggest plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) has similar functionality, might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The only problem I can see with that plugin is that there has been no development since March 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at jQuery UI's [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)? I think you could make this work without too much extra work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it's tarting to look like....

Comment: Here's an example to replicate the functionality using autocomplete: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/

Answer (score 1):

I know you're asking for jQuery, but if you ever switched libraries (unlikely), or wanted to adapt a current one, take a look at [this post](http://ajaxian.com/archives/facebook-style-input-box); it should be quite easy to adapt MooTools code to jQuery.

## And then

[I found the jQuery version](http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/). This version requires jQuery 1.6.*, but that's as simple as downloading a new release from the jQuery site.